# How do I fix pynput controller not working

Tags: python, pynput

code

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, controller

keyboard = controller

keyboard.press('A')
keyboard.release
```

error message

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, controller
importError: cannot import name 'controller' from 'pynput.keyboard'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Controller` needs to be capitalized:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller
```